# Sqlite. How to get value of Auto Increment Primary Key after Insert, other than last_insert_rowid()?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am using Sqlite3 with Flask microframework, but this question concerns only the Sqlite side of things..

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
g.db.execute('INSERT INTO downloads (name, owner, mimetype) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', [name, owner, mimetype])
file_entry = query_db('SELECT last_insert_rowid()')
g.db.commit()
```

The `downloads` table has another column with the following attributes:  `id integer primary key autoincrement,`

If two people write at the same time the code above could produce errors.

Transactions can be messy. In Sqlite is there a neat built in way of returning the primary key generated after doing an INSERT ?

Comment: Please read the documentation for last_insert_rowid (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html); it's local to the database connection.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am using object-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve inserted id after inserting row in SQLite using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242756/how-to-retrieve-inserted-id-after-inserting-row-in-sqlite-using-python)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The way you're doing it is valid. There won't be a problem if the above snipped is executed concurrently by two scripts. `last_insert_rowid()` returns the rowid of the latest INSERT statement for the connection that calls it. You can also get the rowid by doing `g.db.lastrowid`.