# How to retrieve inserted id after inserting row in SQLite using Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

How to retrieve inserted id after inserting row in SQLite using Python? I have table like this:

```
id INT AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
username VARCHAR(50),
password VARCHAR(50)
```

I insert a new row with example data `username="test"` and `password="test"`. How do I retrieve the generated id in a transaction safe way? This is for a website solution, where two people may be inserting data at the same time. I know I can get the last read row, but I don't think that is transaction safe. Can somebody give me some advice?

Answer (score 350, accepted):

You could use [cursor.lastrowid](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) (see "Optional DB API Extensions"):

```py
connection=sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE foo (id integer primary key autoincrement ,
                                    username varchar(50),
                                    password varchar(50))''')
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo (username,password) VALUES (?,?)',
               ('test','test'))
print(cursor.lastrowid)
# 1
```

If two people are inserting at the same time, as long as they are using different `cursor`s, `cursor.lastrowid` will return the `id` for the last row that `cursor` inserted:

```py
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo (username,password) VALUES (?,?)',
               ('blah','blah'))

cursor2=connection.cursor()
cursor2.execute('INSERT INTO foo (username,password) VALUES (?,?)',
               ('blah','blah'))

print(cursor2.lastrowid)        
# 3
print(cursor.lastrowid)
# 2

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo (id,username,password) VALUES (?,?,?)',
               (100,'blah','blah'))
print(cursor.lastrowid)
# 100
```

Note that `lastrowid` returns `None` when you insert more than one row at a time with `executemany`:

```py
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO foo (username,password) VALUES (?,?)',
               (('baz','bar'),('bing','bop')))
print(cursor.lastrowid)
# None
```

Comment: There is also the [`last_insert_rowid()` SQL function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid), allowing you to insert the last row id as a foreign key in a *next* insert statement, entirely in SQL.

Comment: appears Python's sqlite3 lastrowid uses `last_insert_rowid` underneath https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/blob/e728ffbcaeb7bfae1d6b7165369bd0ae16cabf95/src/cursor.c (which isn't guaranteed threadsafe but seems the only option FWIW). See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2127138/32453

Comment: Here's the direct link to [`cursor.lastrowid`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#lastrowid)

Comment: Btw, this works for `INSERT` but does not work for `UPDATE`. But when updating a row, you probably already have the corresponding row id anyways (just took me a while to figure this out...).

Comment: What is meant by "id"?  Is it referring to an id column as integer?  How does it know, what if I don't have an id column for a certain table?

Answer (score 55):

All credits to [@Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) in the comments:

You can use the function [`last_insert_rowid()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid):

> The `last_insert_rowid()` function returns the `ROWID` of the last row insert from the database connection which invoked the function. The `last_insert_rowid()` SQL function is a wrapper around the `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()` C/C++ interface function.

### [SQLite 3.35](https://www3.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html)'s `RETURNING` clause:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name TEXT,
  last_name TEXT
);

INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name)
VALUES ('Jane', 'Doe')
RETURNING id;
```

returns requested columns of the inserted row in `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements.  Python usage:

```py
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?)'
               ' RETURNING id',
               ('Jane', 'Doe'))
row = cursor.fetchone()
(inserted_id, ) = row if row else None
```

Comment: The `LAST_INSERT_ROWID()` function is specific to SQLite. The `cursor.lastrowid` property is part of the Python DB-API specification so it should be more portable.

Comment: Note that the `RETURNING` clause works with `cursor.execute` but won't work with `cursor.executemany`. Python will complain that "executemany() can only execute DML statements."

Comment: Depending on your program you should also be careful with race conditions, if multiple threads might be writing to the database in parallel. In that case you can't assume that last_insert_rowid will the row you've just inserted. Thankfully RETURNING can now be used to solve this, although it's not yet available everywhere.

Comment: SQLite only allows a single writer at once, so that shouldn't be possible @laurent. No?

Comment: That would be possible if something writes to the database between your write and the moment you call last_insert_rowid.