# INSERT and SELECT in one step with JOIN

Tags: join, sqlite, sql-insert

I am using SQLite3 and Python 3. I need to select the primary key value of a newly inserted record. The primary keys are autoincremented, I prefer to keep it that way (rather than generating primary keys myself and keeping track of them in Python). I do this in two steps (`SELECT` after `INSERT`) but want it in a single step for efficiency, using a `JOIN`.

[Using `cursor.lastrowid`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6242813/621762) is faster than two `execute` statements (`timeit` uses linked example):

```
$ python -m timeit -s "\
> import sqlite3;\
> connection=sqlite3.connect(':memory:');\
> cursor=connection.cursor();\
> cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE foo (id integer primary key autoincrement ,\
>                                     username varchar(50),\
>                                     password varchar(50))''')" "\
> cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo (username,password) VALUES (?,?)',\
>                ('test','test'));\
> found = cursor.execute('''SELECT id FROM foo \
>                                     WHERE username='test' \
>                                     AND password='test' ''')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.1 usec per loop
$
$ python -m timeit -s "\
> import sqlite3;\
> connection=sqlite3.connect(':memory:');\
> cursor=connection.cursor();\
> cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE foo (id integer primary key autoincrement ,\
>                                     username varchar(50),\
>                                     password varchar(50))''')" "\
> cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo (username,password) VALUES (?,?)',\
>                ('test','test'));\
> found = cursor.lastrowid"
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.74 usec per loop
$
```

How to do this as a `JOIN` instead, so it is still involves a single `execute` but is strictly limited to SQL commands?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve inserted id after inserting row in SQLite using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242756/how-to-retrieve-inserted-id-after-inserting-row-in-sqlite-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do joins in `INSERT` statements.

If you want to use SQL commands, you could use the [last_insert_rowid SQL function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid).
However, the same value is already returned by the `INSERT` command and can be read with the `Cursor` object's [lastrowid property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.lastrowid) in Python, or the equivalent in other languages' database wrappers.

Answer (score -1):

it did work ok for me.
i'm using in a trigger:

```
insert into tbl(currency)
select instrument.currency, price.lastprice 
from instrument
inner join price on price.instrument=instrument.symbol
where instrument.symbol=new.instrument
on conflict do nothing;
```