# Is there any way to get id of inserted row inside sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there any way to get id of inserted row inside sqlite ?
I have `.plist` ( which contains only array of couple keys/values ) and I have parsed into `array of dictionaries`. I have to insert into `table_one` name from key ( just once because name is the same in every dictionary inside array ) and get id and the insert dictionary like row ( three values ) into `table_two` but to have parent_id column set to id of previous inserted row into `table_one`.
How to solve this ?

Comment: What library are you using? Here is how to get the last insert id using the low-level sqlite library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6242813/866915

Answer (score 1):

In Python, the cursor object has the [lastrowid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.lastrowid) attribute:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO foo(bar, baz) VALUES (?, ?)",
               ["hello", 12345])
foo_id = cursor.lastrowid
```