# Querying in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I'm building a database on python 2.7 using sqlite3 and I have reached a small problem.

Basically I have two tables which each store the following information:

**Tweet**:

```
user_name, 
tweet_time, 
tweet_text
```

**User**:

```
user_name, 
user_description, 
user_followers, 
user_verified, 
user_location
```

I am trying to add a function which prompts the user to enter a string, and every row in both tables which contains the submitted string, which will be found in the tweet_text column, is deleted.

The problem I'm having is that the 'User' Table does not contain a column tweet_text so I'm not sure how to delete corresponding rows in this table without actually having to add a tweet_text column.

What I have so far is just a simple delete query on the 'Tweet' Table.

```
delete_string = raw_input("Which string would you like to be removed from your database?: ")
c.execute("DELETE FROM Tweet WHERE tweet_text LIKE ?", ('%'+delete_string+'%',))
```

I'm wondering if there is any way to delete the corresponding rows in the 'User' Table without having to explicitly include tweet_text as a column.

I'm relatively inexperienced on python and this is my first time using query writing so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far

Comment: It isn't much but I've added it to the question

Comment: You want to delete the user from User table and tweet from Tweet table if match is found, Right?

Comment: I want to delete the whole row from both tables

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you may delete by querying the `username` using the `tweet_text` column but I do not believe you wish to delete the username if you have 2 tweets from the same user and you delete one.

I would probably suggest this:

```
# Fetch all users with a tweet_text that is similar to the delete_string
res = c.execute("SELECT user_name FROM Tweet WHERE tweet_text LIKE ?", ('%'+delete_string+'%',)).fetchall()

# If any user is found
if res:
    # Get his username
    user_name = res[0][0]
    # Delete the tweet
    c.execute("DELETE FROM Tweet WHERE tweet_text LIKE ?", ('%'+delete_string+'%',))
    # If he has no more tweets in the database
    if c.execute("SELECT 1 FROM Tweet WHERE user_name = ?", (user_name)).fetchone() is None:
        # Delete the user.
        c.execute("DELETE FROM User WHERE user_name = ?", (user_name))
```

1. First you fetch the user_name if the tweet exists
2. Then you delete the tweet
3. Then you check if there are more tweets from the same user.
4. If there are none you delete him from the database.

If you wish, you may support multiple users like so:

```
# Get all users with similar tweets
res = c.execute("SELECT user_name FROM Tweet WHERE tweet_text LIKE ?", ('%'+delete_string+'%',)).fetchall()

# If there are any
if res:
    # Get their user names (make it a set to avoid repeated names)
    user_names = set(u[0] for u in res)
    # Delete all the similar tweets
    c.execute("DELETE FROM Tweet WHERE tweet_text LIKE ?", ('%'+delete_string+'%',))
    for user in user_names:
        # Check for each user if he has more tweets in the database
        if c.execute("SELECT 1 FROM Tweet WHERE user_name = ?", (user,)).fetchone() is None:
            # If he has none, delete him.
            c.execute("DELETE FROM User WHERE user_name = ?", (user_name))
```

**UPDATE:**

If you have the same amount of rows, you must have an identifier(rowid) which will tie the tweet and the user. Define the tweet database as so: (The important part is the identifier)

```
identifier INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
user_name TEXT, 
tweet_time DATETIME,
tweet_text TEXT
```

And the User database as so:

```
identifier PRIMARY KEY,
user_name TEXT, 
user_description TEXT, 
...
```

Upon inserting rows to the tweet database, use `cursor.lastrowid` in order to fetch the generated identifier and insert the generated identifier together with the user to the Users database. You should probably do it in the same transaction. Upon deleting, delete from both databases where the identifier is the same.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242756/how-to-retrieve-inserted-id-after-inserting-row-in-sqlite-using-python) stackoverflow question and the [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) documentation regarding rowid or identifier columns.

Here's an example:

```
# When adding
with connection:
    cursor = connection.execute("INSERT INTO Tweet (user_name, tweet_time, tweet_text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (user, time, text))
    rowid = cursor.lastrowid
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO User (identifier, user_name, user_description, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ...", (rowid, user, desc, ...))

# When deleting
tweet_ids = c.execute("SELECT identifier FROM Tweet WHERE tweet_text LIKE ?", ('%'+delete_string+'%',)).fetchall()
if tweet_ids:
    cursor.executemany("DELETE FROM Tweet WHERE identifier = ?", tweet_ids)
    cursor.executemany("DELETE FROM User WHERE identifier = ?", tweet_ids)

# Or one line when deleting (I'm not sure if it works)
c.execute("DELETE tweet, user FROM Tweet tweet JOIN User user "
          "ON tweet.identifier = user.identifier "
          "WHERE tweet.tweet_text LIKE ?", ('%'+delete_string+'%',))
```

Comment: No I only want to delete the rows where the tweet_text column contains the submitted string. For example, if a username has two tweets in the database but only one of them contain the submitted string, then only the row containing this string should be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, would you possibly be able to briefly explain what this code does at each step?

Comment: @JordanHunt Fully explained and updated. No problem :-)

Comment: I'm getting the following error:

`res = c.execute("QUERY user_name FROM Tweet WHERE tweet_text LIKE ?", ('%'+delete_string+'%',))

OperationalError: near "QUERY": syntax error`

Comment: @JordanHunt Should be `SELECT` not `QUERY`, sorry.

Comment: I've run using the bottom code and the row is deleting from the Tweet table but nothing from the User table.

Comment: @JordanHunt The bottom code should delete in case the user has no more tweets. You may remove the `if` statement if you wish to always remove the user.

Comment: So what would happen in the scenario where a user has two tweets, one containing the string to be deleted and one not? He would then have 2 rows in the database, the row containing the submitted string would be deleted from the 'Tweet' table, but not from the 'User' table.

Comment: Exactly. The user table has one row per user and the tweet table can have many tweets per user. You should delete the user only if there are no tweets left. (Again, that's what I understood from your question)

Comment: Sorry this is my fault for not wording my question correctly. Basically what I want is a database with two tables Tweet and User which both have the exact same amount of rows. If a user has more than one tweet in the table it's fine, the reason i want a delete function is in case there are any unwanted strings. For example, if i were to build a database using data retrieved from twitter with ferarri as my main word, there will occasionally be unwanted entries with 'music' as a string which I don't want in the database, therefore those rows should be deleted.

Comment: if a user happens to have a tweet I want to keep and another tweet which contains 'music', the row which contains 'music' should be deleted from both tables. If however the user has two tweets which I would like to keep, then the user should have two rows in the table nothing should be deleted.

Comment: @JordanHunt Updated accordingly.

Comment: Hi @JordanHunt if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this from my mind but try this query:

```
DELETE tweet, user 
FROM Tweet tweet JOIN User user ON tweet.user_name = user.user_name
WHERE tweet.tweet_text LIKE ?;
```

Although what you're looking for is [this](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions), `ON DELETE CASCADE`.
That will automatically delete it from foreign key table, which will be your `User` table.

Make sure to enable foreign key support in SQLite

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```