# How to retrieve inserted id after inserting row in SQLite using C#?

Tags: .net, sqlite

I am asking the C# equivalent [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242756/how-to-retrieve-inserted-id-after-inserting-row-in-sqlite-using-python). When I insert a row of data that has an auto-increment primary key, how can I then read the primary key back?

I need this for SQlite ([this answers for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373461/execute-insert-command-and-return-inserted-id-in-sql)).

thanks - dave

Comment: Which sqlite3 bindings are you using?

Comment: We're using the SQlite ADO.NET connector. System.Data.SQLite version 1.0.108.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// IDbCommand cmd
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
return ((SQLiteConnection) cmd.Connection).LastInsertRowId;
```

Very easy :)