# Python - Flask - Stop page from re-submitting a post request

Tags: python, html, forms, sqlite, flask

How can I stop Flask from re-adding form data to database on refresh?

My `form.html` sends data to `approved.html` like so:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        element = db_name(request.form.get('element'))
        db.session.add(element)
        db.session.commit()
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('approved.html', current=element)
```

This so I can display the data from the form and let the user know entry has been added. But the problem is whenever I refresh approved.html which displays the form data, another copy of this entry is added to the database.

Comment: Have you declared `methods=['GET', 'POST']` in route??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the browser stores the state of the last request and refreshing will re-submit the form, leading to another entry in your database. This is also why it's normal practice to redirect on the server-side after successful form submission. See [Preventing POST on reloading a form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQFeEscCvTg) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

What you need to do is to successfully handle a successful form request and then redirect the user to a fresh state.

So something like this

```
return redirect(url_for('success'))
```

can be added instead of the `render_template` function which will then be redirected to the assigned function; there you can call the `render_template` of your choice.

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense.  Would you know how is it that I can fetch the ID that was auto generated when the entry was added? This so I can display a  - added successfully - message.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242756/how-to-retrieve-inserted-id-after-inserting-row-in-sqlite-using-python) what you are looking for? You can also use that method to fetch the last record before the entry is made and then once the new entry is inserted; check if they are same or different. In the latter case you can simply display that value