# Best way to find in database

Tags: python, sqlite, class

I am implementing a database in Python for animals. Class to create an `Animal` object:

```py
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name: str, animal_type: str, birth_date: str, added_date: str, gender: str,
        description=None, image=None) -> None:

        self.id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.name = name.capitalize()
        self.animal_type = animal_type.capitalize()
        self.birth_date = birth_date
        self.added_date = added_date
        self.gender = gender
        self.description = description
        self.image = image
```

On the database table the only UNIQUE key is `id`. If I want to get a specific animal from the database all properties of that animal should match. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

When I create a new animal a new UUID will be created, so if I want to find or update a specific animal in the database I can't find the animal using the UUID.

Comment: not really sure of what is being asked, but from what I understood & if it helps you can use like query in combination with OR.
E.g. where name like "%keyword%" or description like "%keyword%" and so on.

Comment: So, let me try to clarify this. My problem is, every time that I have to find an animal in the database I need to match all of the properties of that animal like:
name =new_name
animal_type = new_animal_type
birth_date = new_ birth_date
....
I need to match everything because I have repeated animals, it's improbably.
I was trying to find a better way to do this.

Comment: What's wrong with filtering by ID?

Comment: If you want to get a specific animal from the database, why wouldn't you know the id? If you know all the other values, why would you need to look anything up at all? Please give a full concrete example of what you're trying to do. Actual executable code demonstrating your use case; [mre]

Comment: You could use a composite key as the ID if you want to be able to search for an ID without knowing it prior

Comment: @Matt Can you please give a sample for that composite key. I am not able to use the UUID for searching because it is random. Imagine that the use wants to delete an animal from the db, I would like to have some specific property where i could search for it in the db and delete the animal. But with UUID I am not able to do it

Comment: @MatBailie Imagine this:

```animal = Animal(
    name = "Bella",
    animal_type="Dog",
    added_date="2022-01-15",
    birth_date="2022-03-10",
    gender="Female"
)
```

I have that animal in the db and now I want to delete it. The UUID.was generate when I create de Animal object so I don't know what is the UUID. Also I can't match by name because I can have more animals with the same name....

Comment: So how would you differentiate between animals where all the attributes are the same then? Would you not need the ID?

Comment: @tbotl It is not a programming issue, but a database design issue. The database cannot guess which record you want. You need to provide enough data to uniquely identify an animal. Consider another unique index consisting of (name, animal_type, birth_date). If this is enough - enforce uniqueness when adding a new animal. If this is not enough to be unique, you just need more fields, noone can help this.
Of course, in some front-end application, you may filter the records one field at a time until you find only one record that matches.

Comment: The solution is to keep a record of the generated id value. Every database has a bespoke means to return the generated value, and most ORMs have ways to interface with that. So, which database are you using, and which ORM are you using?

Comment: @MatBailie I am using sqlite with python. I am not using a ORM yet

Comment: Then whatever you're doing to create new rows in the database should probably use this; https://stackoverflow.com/a/60045014/53341

Comment: @tbotl [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? What problem is the script and database meant to solve (what's the end goal here)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a composite key instead of a UUID as your primary key. If you don't have access to the PK and want to know it without querying for it.

```
CREATE TABLE course_grades (
    quarter_id INTEGER,
    course_id TEXT,
    student_id INTEGER,
    grade INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(quarter_id, course_id, student_id)
);

SELECT *
FROM course_grades
WHERE quarter_id = 1 
  AND course_id = 3
  AND student_id = 5
```