# Log primary key when new record added to table in Python SQLite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

So I have a function which creates a new object instance to represent an account, and add the account to an accounts table in a database with SQLite3. The database table has 3 columns, one of which is a primary key accountID column, which is set automatically by SQL. My object instance needs to know this accountID so it can find itself in the database in the future, but I'm unsure how to do this. My code:

```
def createAccount(self, name, balance):
    #ensure account name has been entered
    if name == "":
        messagebox.showwarning(title = "Error", message = "You did not enter an account name.")
        return

    #Insert new record into accounts table (primary key set automatically)
    self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO accounts(name, balance) VALUES(?,?)""", (name, balance))

    #Create a new Account object instance and add to accounts dictionary
    self.accounts[name] = Account(self, self.accountContainer, accountID, name, balance)
```

The issue is passing the accountID into the Account initialiser; I don't know how to acquire this without querying the database for the record I just created using the name and balance I have, which sounds like a rather messy solution. Any work around ideas?

Comment: if the ID is chosen by the DBMS then querying the table might be the only solution (and hope you don't have duplicates...). IMO you'd be better off setting the ID yourself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sqlite. How to get value of Auto Increment Primary Key after Insert, other than last\_insert\_rowid()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442033/sqlite-how-to-get-value-of-auto-increment-primary-key-after-insert-other-than)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqlite3 `Cursor` object has a [`lastrowid`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.lastrowid) attribute:

> This read-only attribute provides the rowid of the last modified row. It is only set if you issued an `INSERT` or a `REPLACE` statement
>   using the `execute()` method. For operations other than `INSERT` or
>   `REPLACE` or when `executemany()` is called, `lastrowid` is set to `None`.
>
> If the `INSERT` or `REPLACE` statement failed to insert the previous successful rowid is returned.
>
> *Changed in version 3.6:* Added support for the `REPLACE` statement.

So after your `execute()`:

```
accountID = self.cursor.lastrowid
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you :)